# Where do Grails domain classes get their query methods from?

Tags: java, grails

The same question could be asked about controllers, etc. How does the compiler find the methods/fields that grails artifacts magically have? I am trying to design something similar in pure Java/Spring and would like to know how I can accomplish something like this.

Comment: This is done either using Traits (in later versions of Grails) or meta programming (older versions of Grails) in Groovy.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Can you post an answer with an example? That would be sweet.

Comment: "This is done either using Traits (in later versions of Grails) or meta programming (older versions of Grails) in Groovy" - @JoshuaMoore Even in newer versions of Grails, not all query methods are rigged up with traits.  For example, `where` queries are rigged up with AST transformations that are applied at the site where the query is called.

Comment: In all versions of Grails, dynamic finders rely on runtime metaprogramming with `methodMissing`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown so it sounds like this is something that would be impossible using pure Java then, if it relies on Groovy AST transforms?

Comment: @zero01alpha That is right.  AST Transformations, traits and runtime metaprogramming are all used to support our query mechanisms and Java doesn't really support any of those directly.  You can kind of emulate each of those in different ways with technologies like AOP but Java does not have direct counterparts to any of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the compiler find the methods/fields that grails artifacts
>   magically have?

The compiler doesn't really find the methods, at least not for all query mechanisms.  For example, dynamic finders are not resolved at compile time.  They are handled with dynamic dispatch at runtime.  `where` queries are rigged up at compile time and the "how" is a little involved but in short, we have compile time AST transformations that look for calls to the static `where` method on a domain class and when one of those is encountered, the AST transformation at compile time generates the code necessary to carry out the query at runtime.  Methods like `get(id)` and `list()` are defined in a trait which Grails adds to all domain classes at compile time.

> I am trying to design something similar in pure Java/Spring and would
>   like to know how I can accomplish something like this.

None of the approaches that I described above have direct counterparts which could be implemented in Java.  All of those techniques rely on features provided by Groovy.

HTH

**EDIT**

The title of the question is currently "Where do Grails domain classes get their query methods from?" so I answered specifically in the context of query methods for domain classes.  For the more general "How does the compiler find the methods/fields that grails artifacts magically have?", the comments above still generally apply.